# Restangular - send several params on RestangularService.one()

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, restangular

I'd like to know if it is possible to send more than one param in `RestangularService.one(id)`?
here is the code I have:

```
r = Restangular.service("patients")
patient: (patientId) ->
  r.one(patientId).get().then (response) ->
    return response.patient
```

is it possible to send more data? something like:

```
patient: (patientId, data1, data2)
```

To be more explicit:
Here is the result I get by `r.one(patientId).get()`:

`{"format"=>"json", "controller"=>"api/patients", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"patientId"}`

I'd like to have something like:

`{"format"=>"json", "controller"=>"api/patients", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"patientId", "data1" =>"value", "data2" => "value"}`

Comment: I finally created a custom controller action to this and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional query parameters are sent in the get method:

```
r.one(patientId).get({
    data1: "data1Value",
    data2: "data2Value"
})
```